# MySQL unclearness about DataType TIMESTAMP with DefaultValue CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, datatypes, timestamp

In `MySQL InnDB engine` I created TableColumn with data type `TIMESTAMP` and put there as default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but this value are always changed to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when I update that by using JDBC or MySQL Administrator GUI,

my questions are

1) is this feature by default and I have to remove `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` from Table settings and update this column standard way(s)

2) is there some option / setting that allows me to switch on/off this feature

Sql engine is `MySQL 5.1.29-rc community`

Comment: Can you add your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html), a TIMESTAMP can be auto-initialized, auto-updated, both, or neither. The apparent caveat is this:

> With neither DEFAULT nor ON UPDATE clauses, it is the same as DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

So, if you don't explicitly give the column a default/on update clause, it will do both. If you don't want to default or auto-update, give the default a '0':

```
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0
```

Comment: Everything needed is in your first link. +1 !!!

Comment: I saw, read and pretty ignore that, before I post this question, thanks for kick +1